# How to run a JAR file using Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

How to execute a JAR file from Jenkins?

I have a JAR output from a gradle build section, i want to execute this JAR file after it created. I am using a Jenkins platform setup in windows server. I don't have any separate node for execution, master itself acts as both server and node.

Tried several ways but not working as expected. The JAR file is working if i run in a normal windows batch command window but the same command is not working if i executed it from a Jenkins windows batch command build section.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In which way does it not work? No effect? Wrong effect? Crash? Hang?

Comment: can you paste the batch command you use to run in Jenkins

Comment: @rohit : start java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=XYZ %JAR_PATH%\test.jar

Comment: @Yunnosch: There is no effect..the jar is not executing (jar file is called inside the batch script)

Comment: First: Remove the trailing "start", so the JVM will be called in the same shell, and you will get the output if any errors had happened.

Comment: Anyway, I'd bet the order of options in your call is incorrect: It should be `java -D... -jar jarfile`

Comment: I have given the following commands in the post build script and it started working. The first command will kill the running instance of the JAR an start the new instance as well....Thanks all for the support

for /f "tokens=1" %%i in ('jps -m ^| find "%BIN_JAR_NAME%"') do ( taskkill /F /PID %%i )
start java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=**** %OUTPUT_PATH%\%BIN_JAR_NAME%

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add useful information, instead of hiding it in comments.

Comment: Please take the [tour].

Comment: Thank you all (rohit, Yunnosch and Little Santi) for the great support...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following commands in the post build script started working. The first command will kill the running instance of the JAR and start the new instance as well.

```
 for /f "tokens=1" %%i in ('jps -m ^| find "%BIN_JAR_NAME%"') do ( taskkill /F /PID %%i ) start java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=**** %OUTPUT_PATH%\%BIN_JAR_NAME%
```

Comment: This answer was hidden in the comments from OP.